# How to move folder in /usr/share/themes

Tags: settings, themes, sudo, pkexec

I want to put a folder on `/usr/share/themes` but it says permission denied. How can i paste a folder on this location?

Comment: note that in order to add themes, you do not necessarily need to use the protected location, but instead use `~/.local/share/themes` (the same logic for icons in `~/.local/share/icons` and  application launchers in `~/.local/share/applications`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can right-click on the *Files* icon in the dock and select *New Window As Administrator* from the menu. Once the window has opened you can paste your folder there.
- Or you can do it in a terminal with `sudo` as well:

  ```
  sudo mv original_folder /usr/share/themes
  ```